# Excel VBA Macro: Swap Link Path Only

Tags: excel, vba

I have a current module which updates 2 different workbook links within each workbook located in a user selected folder.  The "master" workbooks contained in the links must be open during the execution and all the code does is open and close all workbooks in the folder.  I had brute forced my way through examples I found online to put this together, so be easy on the judgements.

```
Public Sub OpenClose()

Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog
Dim myFolder As String

> 'Have User Select Folder to Save to with Dialog Box
Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

With FldrPicker
>     .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
>     .AllowMultiSelect = False
If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub 'Check if user clicked cancel button
myFolder = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With
Dim fso As Object
Dim folder As Object
Dim file As Object
Path = myFolder
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set folder = fso.GetFolder(Path)

With Application
>         .DisplayAlerts = False
>         .ScreenUpdating = False
>         .EnableEvents = False
>         .AskToUpdateLinks = False
End With

For Each file In folder.Files
If Right(file.Name, 4) = "xlsm" Or Right(file.Name, 3) = "xls" Then
Workbooks.Open Path & file.Name
ActiveWorkbook.Close True
End If
Next

With Application
>         .DisplayAlerts = True
>         .ScreenUpdating = True
>         .EnableEvents = True
>         .AskToUpdateLinks = True
End With
End Sub
```

What I'd like to do now is provide an option for the user to change the directory address for the "master" file pathways for each link within the workbooks in the user selected folder.  The "master" workbooks will always be located in the same folder, so the pathway to that folder can be identical for each link, but the respective file names of each link need to be retained.

Ideally the user would input the new directory address of the "master" workbooks within a cell before using Ctrl+q to run the VBA and require no further input after execution.  This is probably trivial, but my experience level is near zero with VBA.

Comment: I assume setting something called ActiveWorkbook.FilePath might be a thing?  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Or ActiveWorkbook.UpdateLink Path?